# how to download older version of git project

Tags: git, branch

I have project on GIT. I need to test older version of it, without loosing actual version. I prefer to have 2 folders on my computer: one keeps the newest version, one keeps the older version. Project is in one branch. How to do that? I am using SourceTree and my project is C++ made in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Use `git log` to find the older commit you're interested in, the use `git checkout` to check out a working copy. For more information on how to use `git`, see http://www.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Use the [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree/2.13.0) feature.

That will let you have your repository cloned with the new version checked out.
And create a worktree in another folder with another older branch checked out.

Do something like:

`git worktree add ..\old_version_worktree old_branch_name`